# Login failed for user 'myid' on launching the .net core web app from azure app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, appsettings

I have a pipeline that deploys app service, sql server, and sql db in Azure. Deploys the zipped application in app service.

However when I run the following command from Console under Development Tools I get an exception.

Command

```
dotnet mywebapp.dll
```

Exception

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'myid'.
```

I have a sql server with two DBs, below is the code in startup.cs for connection string(.net 6 web app)

```
 services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDBContext"));
                options.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Ignore(CoreEventId.NavigationBaseIncludeIgnored));
            });

services.AddHangfire(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServerStorage(() => new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyHangfireContext")), hangfireConfig);
            });
```

hangfireConfig has been defined as a separate variable (SqlServerStorageOptions)

My connection string in appsettings

```
"MyHangfireContext": "Server=tcp:mydb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=HangfireDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myid;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
    "MyDBContext": "Server=tcp:mydb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyAppDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myid;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
```

Also to add, this app setting is an environment specific app setting and I have the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT defined so it is picked up.

Comment: Did you check whether it is possible to access database with same user in SSMS or query editor?

Comment: Yes I can access query editor for my azure sql db using the credential in connection string

Comment: Just to add I also have client ip and app id added in Firewall rules

Comment: Could you please provide where you running the .net App?

Comment: I am sorry I do not follow the question. I have it deployed in Azure App Service, it is a .net 6 web app. Do you need any additional information?

Comment: I have also tried different versions of the connection string, by adding Trusted_Connection, Integrated Security but get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your descriptions, I thought the issue related to the deployment. So please follow my steps to troubleshoot the issue.

#### Troubleshooting Steps

1. Open  `App Service Editor (Preview)` and check the `appsettings.json` file.
   Check the connectionstring is correct or not ?

   [image]

   [image]
2. If the connection string is correct, and the issue still occurs, so could you hard code it inside your Program.cs file. To check the issue related to code or environment ?
3. Please create a temp rule to allow all ip to access the db in Firewall.

   [image]
4. You have confirmed the connection string works well in SSMS, then please try to connect it by using vs2022 and get the new connection string, I know we can get it from azure portal, please try it.

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

Copy the new connection string, and use it in your appsettings.json file or add it in azure portal.

The new connectionstring format is

```
Data Source=tcp:your_sqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db_name;User ID=jason;Password=********;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False
```

5. Please check whether there is an old configuration in the azure portal. For the checking steps, please refer to the last screenshot.

**Tips**

Usually our test database link is placed in the appsettings.json file, and there is no need to modify it when deploying. We can add server dependencies when VS2022 is released.

[image]

It doesn't matter if you use other methods, we can add it manually in the azure portal, and the configuration in the appsetting.json file will be overwritten after adding.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jason for troubleshooting steps, I do have answers for a few but I will perform the remaining ones and will give you a consolidated response

Comment: @Lucky  Believe me, following these steps will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still with the same issue: I checked App Service Editor from Portal, the connection string is fine. I am yet to try hard coding the connection string into my program/startup. I was getting IP related error at first but then I added the app service ip and then received the current error for which I posted this question (I still went ahead and did add your allow_all rule but sadly no luck). No I cannot connect to it using SSMS due to some restrictions, I confirmed I can access query editor (Portal) using the same credentials.

Comment: Yes I did read about the app settings from portal overriding the app setting json, and I added both in Connection string with the same name as my app setting file but ended up with the same issue. I am again sharing my current version of connection string format. "MyHangfireContext": "Server=tcp:mydb.database.windows.net,1433;Database=HangfireDB;User ID=myid;Password=mypwd;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;"
Similarly for MyDBContext

Comment: I did hardcoding of connection strings too but still in the same situation: Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''

Comment: Hi @Lucky, have you tried to connect to the database via vs2022?

Comment: @Lucky You can get new connectionstring from there, and hardcode, try again, waiting for your response.

Comment: Unfortunately due to some restrictions from my machine I cannot connect to the azure sql db from ssms or vs, any other way I can try to get it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253585/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-lucky).

Comment: Thank you so much Jason, the step 4 worked for me taking the connection string by connecting to sql db from VS 2022

Comment: @Lucky Glad to hear you have solved the issue. Have a nice day